# Angular sets input field to ng-invalid-min when trying to update it dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to update an `<input type="number">` field depending on the chosen option in a `<select>`, as well as its `min=""` and `max=""`,  but the the input field gets red and empty : ionic puts these classes in the markup :
`class="ng-valid-max ng-valid-number ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-min ng-invalid-required"`

The `console.logs` on the typeof the input value indicates that they are indeed numbers.

**Edit:** If I comment the snippet of code under : //initialise the values in the weight and unit fields
then the bug disappears...

template.html

```
                <div id="weightdata" class="row">
                    <div id="weighttext"> <!-- class="col-20 enteryourweighttext"> -->
                        My weight:
                    </div>
                    <input id="weightinput" type="number" name="userweight" min="{{data.minWeight}}" max="{{data.maxWeight}}" ng-model="data.userweight" ng-change="saveUserWeight()" required></input>
                     <div id="weightunitradios"> 
                        <ion-checkbox class="checkboxes" ng-model="data.weightunit" ng-true-value="kg" ng-false-value="lbs" ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); convertWeightInput();">kg</ion-checkbox>
                        <ion-checkbox class="checkboxes" ng-model="data.weightunit" ng-true-value="lbs" ng-false-value="kg" ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); convertWeightInput();">lbs</ion-checkbox>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

controllers.js:

```
  .controller('WeightlevelCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, sessionService) {



//initialise the values in the weight and unit fields
console.log(sessionService.get('weightunit'))
  if (sessionService.get('weightunit')) {
    $scope.data.weightunit = sessionService.get('weightunit'); 
    console.log(sessionService.get('weightunit') );
  } else {
    $scope.data.weightunit = 'kg';
  };
  if ($scope.data.weightunit === 'kg'){
      $scope.data.minWeight="30";
      $scope.data.maxWeight="140";
    } else {
      $scope.data.minWeight="65";
      $scope.data.maxWeight="310";
    }
  if (sessionService.get('userWeight')) {$scope.data.userweight = sessionService.get('userWeight') } else {$scope.data.userweight = 70};
  if (sessionService.get('userLevel')) {$scope.data.levelvalue = sessionService.get('userLevel') } else {$scope.data.levelvalue = 5};



if (sessionService.get('weightunit')) {
    $scope.data.weightunit = sessionService.get('weightunit'); 
    console.log(sessionService.get('weightunit') );
  } else {
    $scope.data.weightunit = 'kg';
  };
  if ($scope.data.weightunit === 'kg'){
      $scope.data.minWeight="30";
      $scope.data.maxWeight="140";
    } else {
      $scope.data.minWeight="65";
      $scope.data.maxWeight="310";
    }
  if (sessionService.get('userWeight')) {$scope.data.userweight = sessionService.get('userWeight') } else {$scope.data.userweight = 70};
  if (sessionService.get('userLevel')) {$scope.data.levelvalue = sessionService.get('userLevel') } else {$scope.data.levelvalue = 5};


  $scope.convertWeightInput = function () {
    if ($scope.data.weightunit === 'kg'){
      $scope.data.minWeight="30";
      $scope.data.maxWeight="140";
      $scope.data.userweight = parseFloat(Math.round(lbs2kg($scope.data.userweight)));
      console.log(typeof $scope.data.userweight);
      console.log($scope.data.userweight);
    } else {
      $scope.data.minWeight="65";
      $scope.data.maxWeight="310";
      $scope.data.userweight = parseFloat(Math.round(kg2lbs($scope.data.userweight)));
      console.log(typeof $scope.data.userweight);
      console.log($scope.data.userweight);
    }
  }

 $scope.saveWeightUnit = function() {
    sessionService.persist('weightunit', $scope.data.weightunit);
  }

  $scope.saveUserWeight = function() {
    sessionService.persist('userWeight', $scope.data.userweight);
  }

  $scope.saveUserLevel = function() {
    sessionService.persist('userLevel', $scope.data.levelvalue);
  }

})
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had to split the process into two functions like this :

```
 if ($scope.data.weightunit === 'kg'){
      $scope.data.minWeight=30;
      $scope.data.maxWeight=140;
    } else {
      $scope.data.minWeight=65;
      $scope.data.maxWeight=310;
    }
  if (sessionService.get('userWeight')) {$scope.data.userweight = parseInt(sessionService.get('userWeight')) } else {$scope.data.userweight = 70};
  if (sessionService.get('userLevel')) {$scope.data.levelvalue = parseInt(sessionService.get('userLevel')) } else {$scope.data.levelvalue = 5};

  $scope.changeMinMax = function () {
    if ($scope.data.weightunit === 'kg'){
      $scope.data.minWeight=30;
      $scope.data.maxWeight=140;
    } else {
      $scope.data.minWeight=65;
      $scope.data.maxWeight=310;
    }
  }
  $scope.convertWeightInput = function () {
    if ($scope.data.weightunit === 'kg'){
      $scope.data.userweight = parseFloat(Math.round(lbs2kg($scope.data.userweight)));
      console.log(typeof $scope.data.userweight);
      console.log($scope.data.userweight);
    } else {
      $scope.data.userweight = parseFloat(Math.round(kg2lbs($scope.data.userweight)));
      console.log(typeof $scope.data.userweight);
      console.log($scope.data.userweight);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as seen here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404
we need to use `ng-min` and `ng-max` instead of `min` and `max`.